# In Visual Studio 2022, Pressing "F5" to continue sometimes produces spurious message about edits when there are none

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently installed Visual Studio 2022.  I editing a project that was developed in a previous version.  When I use the `F5` key to continue inside the debugger, it sometimes produces this message:

[image]

Once the message appears once, `F5` can not be used again and even in subsequent rebuilds; reappears.  Visual Studio needs to be restarted for `F5` to work again.  Using the continue option from the toolbar always works fine.

What's going on here and are there some things I can try to fix this? With this an a few other bugs I've run into, VS2022 is completely unusable.

Comment: I am surmising this is because every time I run a build, webpack runs and regenerates the  CSS for the site.  I believe this is getting flagged as code changes.  I've turned of hot reload, so we will see if it fixes it.

Comment: I have the same problem, but i don't have webpack or nothing, just plain asp.net core app. It's very frustrating!